# Visual Studio 2013 - errors when editing build definition

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

I get several errors when trying to edit my build definition. This has worked fine before, but I suspect that installing Visual Studio 2015 has messed things up.

History:
First I had Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. At this time there were no problems
Recently I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional.
For licensing reasons, I had to remove VS 2013 Ultimate and install VS 2013 Professional instead.

In VS 2013 Professional-> Team Explorer->Builds I now get an error when I edit my build definition. I suspect that the installation/reinstallation is the cause.

1. Under Process->Items to build I click the add button and get this error message:

*[A]Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll'. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll'.*

Comment: check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces.aspx) it shows about the  Update from 2010 to 2012 , might be the same case here also

Comment: Thx. Editing my xaml does not seem to be an option though, as my colleagues are able to edit the build definition without errors. There must be some local setting/assembly issue on my machine that I can change

Comment: just changee in `TfsBuildServiceHost.exe.config` will do the trick which should be similar to this:

Comment: `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client"publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/><bindingRedirectoldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/></dependentAssembly><dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>`

Comment: Maybe this will work. However I rather not make any server changes. There must be a local setting in registry or other place that could resolve the error locally.

Comment: this setting would be local setting in your config section

Comment: Ok I cannot find the file TfsBuildServiceHost.exe.config anywhere locally. where should it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96980/discussion-between-webruster-and-flodpanter).

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools`

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Have you customized you build process template before?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to:

1. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`. (x is the TFS version)
2. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v10.0`
3. Try resetting settings and add-in settings (**devenv /ResetSettings**) and (**devenv /ResetSkipPkgs**), try rebuilding all templates (**devenv /setup**).